# Is it possible to specify a bandwidth parameter per service instance?

Tags: cisco-ios

I have a physical interface with multiple service instances and policer per service instance:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk allowed vlan none
 switchport mode trunk
 mtu 9192
 service instance 201 ethernet test
  encapsulation dot1q 201
  rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
  l2protocol forward
  service-policy input bw-20Mbps
  service-policy output set-8021p-0
  xconnect 192.0.2.28 18921000 encapsulation mpls
   mtu 1516
 !
 service instance 255 ethernet test2
   encapsulation dot1q 255
   /* output removed for brevity */
```

Currently all the service instances report the SNMP `ifSpeed` value of `1000000000` which is the physical interface bandwidth. Example:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public ME3600X ifDescr.20541
IF-MIB::ifDescr.20541 = STRING: GigabitEthernet0/3.ServiceInstance.201
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public ME3600X ifSpeed.20541
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.20541 = Gauge32: 1000000000
$
```

This messes up statistics in NMS. Is it possible to specify a bandwidth parameter per service instance?

Comment: Even if you could set a `bandwidth` per SI, the command doesn't change the interface speed as reported by `ifSpeed`. (it's just an advisory datum for routing protocols, spanning-tree, etc.) You might see that number from the CISCO-IF-EXTENSION-MIB::cieIfSpeedReceive

Comment: @RickyBeam As each SI has its own SNMP `ifIndex`, then it seems logical for me that one can adjust the `bandwidth` parameter for each SI. Just like in case of Cisco sub-interfaces. Obviously, this does not have to be the `bandwidth` keyword like in case of sub-interfaces or physical interfaces, but for example "snmp bandwidth <value>" or something similar. Unfortunately, as much as I have poked around in the CLI and searched the documentation, then something like this does not seem to exist and SI always reports the physical interface bandwidth.